# How to stop Samsung Galaxy S20 vibrating on resuming and entering lock mode?

Tags: samsung, vibration

My Samsung Galaxy S20 vibrates every time the screen times out and enters lock mode and vice-versa when I press the right button to exit the lock mode and start using the phone.

How do I remove this behavior?

Comment: its just a haptic feedback i guess. is it unbearable?

Comment: I understand, but it's my wife's phone and she's raising hell about it!

Answer (score 0):

1. Someone here has same problem - https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/mobile-apps-services/need-to-disable-vibrate-on-lock-unlock/td-p/1849864
   It is different phone but I guess you can try. It is basically suggesting to turn off NFC.
2. Usual method - Settings>Sounds&vibration. Find settings related to vibration and keyboard feedback. Tweak settings to your liking.