# After I installed an app, the phone now scans NFC every time I unlock the screen (Android 12)

Tags: nfc, android-12

I did not know that an App can modify system behavior like this.

I have phone always on silent. I installed "Xiaomi Wear". During installation in Play Store, the phone made a short vibration. I thought that was weird, since the phone is on silent, and it never vibrates.

Anyway, after installation, the phone is now changed to vibrate every time I unlock it. A short vibration, but with full force (unlike when unlock with fingerprint).

**Apparently, the phone scans NFC every time I unlock it - and since I have a bank card on the back, I guess it vibrates to signify it found something.**

But I don't understand why an app can cause something like this, and how I can prevent it?

Comment: Possibly related: [How to stop Samsung Galaxy S20 vibrating on resuming and entering lock mode?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/235971/44325); this one is due to the NFC setting being enabled. Otherwise, try to identify the cause by following [How to determine which app is causing vibration?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215638/44325)

Comment: Thanks, that led me understand why (NFC is scanning a card on the back of my phone). The question is still why, and how an app can cause this to happen every time the phone is unlocked. I edited the post.

Comment: If it's NFC, then I think that's the Android system itself that does the vibration and the Xiaomi Wear app might be a red-herring. Android system may bypass the user's setting. If possible, follow the second link to be sure which component did the vibration.

Comment: It stopped when I uninstalled Xiaomi Wear, and started again when I reinstalled it. So It's definitely that app that causes it, but I don't understand how that app can make a system wide change like that... Like mentioned, even during installation it made the phone vibrate - before I even opened the app!

Comment: Ah, I see... from the Play Store and its `AndroidManifest.xml`, Xiaomi Wear has the NFC permission. This means that this app is now a candidate to process the NFC tags (handled by `com.xiaomi.wearable.nfc.NfcScanActivity`) and that's why the device now vibrates (done by the Android system, not the app) every time an NFC tag is scanned. Just to clarify since the question has been changed, did you want to prevent the NFC scanning or the vibration?

Comment: I wanted to prevent the scanning, since I don't know what the purpose of scanning every time a phone unlocks is? It doesn't do anything, I get no prompt that NFC is found.

Comment: I would assume that when NFC is enabled it scans periodically while the phone is unlocked.